# Show data sent to WCF in windows form

Tags: c#, wcf, windows

I am hosting a WCF service in windows application, the WCF service receives messages from another windows service and i need to show these messages in text box inside the opened form

How can i implement that ? i am using the following code but it doesn't work:

The form code :

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
private ServiceHost Host;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();          
}  

private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    Host.Close();
}

public void WriteMessage(string message)
{
    richTextBox1.Text += message;
    richTextBox2.Text = message;
}

private void StartBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Host = new ServiceHost(typeof(MonitoringData));
    Host.Open();
    button1.Enabled = false;
}
}
```

The WCF service code :

```
public class MonitoringData : IMonitoringData
{
public void DoWork(string message)
{
    Form1 monitorForm = new Form1();
    monitorForm.WriteMessage(message);            
}
}
```

The form consists from 2 textboxes and one button that start WCF service

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where are you calling the service method to get the return value ?

Comment: I am calling it from another windows service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it, i used the following code in the WCF service and it works correctly :

```
public class MonitoringData : IMonitoringData
{
   public void DoWork(string message)
   {

       Form1 monitorForm = (Form1)System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms[0];
       monitorForm.WriteMessage(message);            
   }
}
```

Comment: Where Quintins answer to accept it ?? and i have propsed that for him but he didn't !! and what is the better to let the question without answer for any visitor or to accept correct answer ?

Comment: Always accept the correct answer.  It's the polite thing to do, and it will ensure that people continue to answer questions you ask.

Comment: I am the one who demanded from Quintins to write his answer to accept it but he didn't so i wrote it and accepted it to help any visitor or member to know the right answer because my message is to send right answer not to show who wrote the right answer because if any one has a problem like my one he will not search who reply the right answer but will search for the right answer and again if Quintins write the answer i will accept it and i gave him VoteUp for his comment because this was the available so what can i do else?? ...

Comment: In my case OpenForms is empty in the WCF-host even when the form is visible. The strange thing is that yesterday it worked and I changed nothing to the code.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem stems from the `DoWork` method, particularly this line

```
Form1 monitorForm = new Form1();
```

You are instantiating a new `Form1` object simply to call the `WriteMessage` method but you never show the form, it simply falls out of scope. If you have an existing reference to a `Form1` class then you should be passing that to call the `WriteMessage` method on the existing form.

Comment: How can i have a reference to Form1 ? is to make the Form1 static ?

Comment: @Ahmy I don't know your application structure, whether or not it is possible for you to pass a reference around of if you need to create a static variable in need to access it.

Comment: What does "System.Windows.Forms.OpenForms[0]" means?

Comment: @Ahmy It is a collection of open forms generally managed for you within a winforms application, however the answer you added using `ActiveForm` should work as well.

Comment: It works for the first time then after then stop working correctly it clashes because the returned active form is null and when i used the line of code you gave me it has a syntax error as class "Forms" doesn't have property called "OpenForms[0]"

Comment: Sorry...`System.Windows.Forms.Application.OpenForms[0]`

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked correctly i need to give you vote +1 so please answer it to give you vote up.. thanks again